# Why PostgreSQL SELECT..WHERE CHAR(#) matches with extra trailing space

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

How does PostgreSQL (not sure about others) SELECT..WHERE with *fixed-size char array* work with extra trailing space?

Create table and simple record:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE T (v CHAR(3) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# INSERT INTO T (v) VALUES ('abc');
INSERT 0 1
```

Test simple match:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM T WHERE v='abc';
  v
-----
 abc
(1 row)
```

Test unmatched case:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM T WHERE v='abcde';
 v
---
(0 rows)
```

Why still **matches with extra trailing space**:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM T WHERE v='abc  ';
  v
-----
 abc
(1 row)
```

Comment: I believe this is how the comparison is defined in the SQL standard -- the shorter string is padded with spaces for the comparison.

Comment: This is because you use `CHAR` type. if you use `TEXT` or `CHARACTER VARYING` instead, match will not happen

Comment: [Don't use char()](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 0):

with `postgres=# SELECT * FROM T WHERE v='abc  ';`

you are doing a cast of 'abc  ' implicitely and Postgres silently truncates trailing whitespace when casting to a varchar.

Comment: According to the [Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html): Values of type character are physically padded with spaces to the specified width n, and are stored and displayed that way. _However, trailing spaces are treated as semantically insignificant and disregarded when comparing two values of type character._  Emphasis mine.